# Internet is working but "apt update" giving this error in windows subsystem for linux

Tags: apt, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Just installed ubuntu 18.04 in wsl. But when I try to install or update system i'm getting this error

```
enter Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
```

/etc/resolv.conf file:

```
nameserver 192.168.43.1 nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

help me!

Comment: Please add output of `grep -ir Proxy /etc/apt` to the question.

Comment: Check hosts files on windows and wsl.  Linux.   >>  linux  /etc/hosts  and on windows "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"

Answer (score 1):

my two cents for **Windows 10 and WSL**

go simple at start...

I have the SAME problem in WSL under Windows 10. same errors.

it was simply Norton Antivirus.

I DO KNOW is very dangerous to stop it, but once stopped (for a while...) Ubuntu starts updating.

:)

before gcc, update ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the following line in my `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file which was causing the `proxyaddress` error:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:port";
```

Commenting out this line, or removing the line completely, got rid of my issue.